# bin/magento setup:di:compile getting 'generated' directory permission is read-only' error

Tags: magento2.3, setup-di-compile

During run bin/magento setup:di:compile getting following error, i gave 777 permission to generated folder still getting error. How to solve the following error,

```
Class Magento\Inventory\Model\Source does not exist
  Class Biztech\Inventorysystementerprise\Controller\Mobileassistantpro\Product\addNewProduct\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate prop
  erly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory
   permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related constru
  ct method, only.
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command from the CLI first :

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/
```